# How can I describe villages with Schema.org?

Tags: schema.org

I know there is [`City`](http://schema.org/City), but I was unable to find any [village](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Village).

How can I describe villages with Schema.org?

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, schema.org doesn't have every type of place, person or object on the planet. At this current time you only have 2 options, which are:

1. `<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">`
2. `<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/City">`

Either are valid because a village, town and city is a *place*. City is more specific, which is also a town, and village could fit under that too...

Answer (score 2):

This may be a linguistically loaded answer, but I think we have to look at this from an American English position <sub><sup><sup>(quickly ducking)</sup></sup></sub>. Since the schema.org vocabulary was put together primarily by American corporations (Google, Bing, Yahoo) it's probably safe to presume that they meant "City" as a generic term for any city/town/village/municipality. This is pretty much in line with the rest of the HTML standard which uses primarily American spelling/terminology for tags.

[This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/65338) and [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/71092) on the English SE site explain a bit further why "City" is the generic word used in this case.

Comment: Questions here can certainly be linguistically loaded for those on different continents... In the U.S., many smaller towns are incorporated as [villages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_divisions_of_New_York#Village) that would commonly be referred to as cities as well. [Geographical databases](http://www.maxmind.com/en/city) also use the term "city" generically.

Answer (score 0):

Just because schema.org supports `City` and not `Village` doesn't make it any less of a `Place`.

In May of this Year, Schema.org introduced the new `Extension` mechanism which you can read about here:
`http://www.schema.org/docs/extension.html`

The *old* way to do this was with "Slash" extensions which was simple to understand - you can find this here: `http://www.schema.org/docs/old_extension.html`

The point is, most Schema.org items and properties are derived from `Thing`, and any properties you *need* that aren't covered by `Place` could either live on it's own as a declared itemtype with no reference to it's parent.

Froma an available Properties standpoint, a `City` is no different than an `AdministrativeArea` which is no different from `Place`: `AdministrativeArea` and all of it's children are merely extensions of Place.